# Append values from Data Extension to url

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, dataextensions

I am looking to append an Id to the end of a url link that will take the user to a specific page depending on their unique Id. I am able to gather the Id within the sending data extension and I am currently using personalization strings to accomplish now (https://m360acceleratorhealthcare-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/%%Id%%).

Additionally, I will need to direct a user to a different page if they are already signed in, would an IF statement work? Also, would I need to use the Redirect or would personalization strings still work, given that the Id we need to append is in the sending Data Extension.

Comment: You'll get more traction on your questions, if you provide some of your work-in-progress code.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
%%[/* Modify to view AMPScript <div style="display:none"> */

var @signedIn, @p1, @p2, @url
set @signedIn = AttributeValue("DECOLUMNNAME1")
set @p1 = AttributeValue("DECOLUMNNAME2")
set @p2 = AttributeValue("DECOLUMNNAME3")

if @signedIn == 1 then
  set @url = concat("http://example.com?p1=",@p1)
else
  set @url = concat("http://example.com?p2=",@p2)
endif

/*</div>*/
]%%

<a href="%%=redirectto(@url)=%%">link</a>
```